# rails, associating 3 different models with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller, associations

I've been ransacking my brain for the last few hours about this and thought I would ask the experts on here for some help.

I have 3 models: User, Posts, Comments. I'm using Devise for authentication.

Users have an avatar field. Posts has_many Comments. Comments belong_to Post.

I want to basically display the user's avatar (located in the Users model) in the Comments. What is the syntax to get comment's user's avatar?

Right now, I have:

```
@post.user.avatar
```

This works, but basically shows the user who posted on every comment avatar pic (not correct). I need to somehow get the commenter's avatar but not sure what the right way to do this is with regards to the controller query / view / model calls.

Associations:

```
Post:
has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :user

Comment:
belongs_to :post

User:
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
```

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: user has_many comments and has_many posts? post has_many comments?

Comment: Please post all of your associations in your User, Post and Comment models (ie `belongs_to` and `has_many`) so that we can see the whole picture.

Comment: Thanks for your note - I've added all the associations in an edit to my original post. Cheers!

Comment: Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Still can't get this to work. Thx!!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a relationship between comments and users. A comment must be made by a user, right? That doesn't exist in what you've said. The comments do belong to the post, but they simultaneously belong to the user who made the comment.

Right now, you are just showing the avatar of the person who posted because that's who the post belongs to.

So for the first comment for a given post, it would be `@post.comments.first.user.avatar`. Now, obviously that could do with some refactoring, but I left it like that for clarity. For example, you could just write in your view to display the post's comments, then create a comment partial view that handles grabbing the comment's user's avatar and displaying it.